# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 24; Attribute "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Estou atualizando um projeto (velho) para as bibliotecas mais recentes, como Spring (da versão 3.2.4.FINAL para a versão 4.3.11.FINAL). Um dos erros que aparece no Tomcat 6 é:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:org/codehaus/xfire/spring/xfire.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [org/codehaus/xfire/spring/xfire.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 24; Attribute "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4276)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from class path resource [org/codehaus/xfire/spring/xfire.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 24; Attribute "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:227)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 24; Attribute "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 39 more
```

Aparentemente é um problema com o XFire. O XML do pacote xfire-spring com problema (versão 1.2.6) é:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

  <import resource="customEditors.xml"/>

  <bean id="xfire.serviceRegistry"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.service.DefaultServiceRegistry"
    singleton="true" /><!-- Here is Line 10 -->

  <bean id="xfire.transportManager"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.transport.DefaultTransportManager"
    singleton="true" init-method="initialize" destroy-method="dispose">
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire" class="org.codehaus.xfire.DefaultXFire"
    singleton="true">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
      <ref bean="xfire.serviceRegistry" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
      <ref bean="xfire.transportManager" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire.typeMappingRegistry"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.aegis.type.DefaultTypeMappingRegistry"
    init-method="createDefaultMappings" singleton="true">
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire.aegisBindingProvider"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.aegis.AegisBindingProvider"
    singleton="true">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
      <ref bean="xfire.typeMappingRegistry" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire.serviceFactory"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ObjectServiceFactory"
    singleton="true">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
      <ref bean="xfire.transportManager" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
      <ref bean="xfire.aegisBindingProvider" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire.servletController"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.transport.http.XFireServletController"
    singleton="true">
    <constructor-arg>
      <ref bean="xfire" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire.messageServiceFactory"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.ObjectServiceFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="xfire.transportManager" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="xfire.messageBindingProvider" />
    <property name="style" value="message" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="xfire.messageBindingProvider"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.service.binding.MessageBindingProvider" />

  <!-- 
  <bean id="commons-attributes"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.spring.config.ServiceFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="commons-attributes" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jsr181"
    class="org.codehaus.xfire.spring.config.ServiceFactoryBean"
    init-method="initialize">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="jsr181" />
  </bean>
 -->
</beans>
```

Meu pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>system</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MySystem</name>
    <version>1.2-20150813</version>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
                    <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                    <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <manifest>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifest>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workDirectory>../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/</workDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>libs-release</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots />
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot-remote</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot-remote</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Maven Repository</id>
            <name>repo1.maven.org</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Maven Repository 2</id>
            <name>repo2.maven.org</name>
            <url>http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- repository> <id>java.net</id> <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/java.net-m2/</url> 
            </repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-3rd-party</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>springsource-repo</id>
            <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.webflow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>spring-security-core-tiger</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.17.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-modules-jcr</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>aparzev</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>aparzev</groupId>
                    <artifactId>doka</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jeceira</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jeceira</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jsr170</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr170</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jug</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jug-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackrabbit-jca</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackrabbit-spi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JackRabbit -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-ocm</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-rmi</artifactId>
            <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-jca</artifactId>
            <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                    <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1211.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>xfire-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <jackrabbit.version>2.13.4</jackrabbit.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.webflow.version>2.4.4.RELEASE</spring.webflow.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Acho que o XFire é muito velho pra usar com essa versão do Spring, mas não queria voltar para a versão 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O XFire não funciona no Spring 3.2 e superiores. O uso do pacote é necessário para a utilização do seguinte Bean (`web-application-config.xml`):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
```

Segundo a própria página do Spring, [`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` foi depreciado a partir da versão 3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html). A ideia por trás desse Bean é permitir o mapeamento de Web Services através de bibliotecas de terceiros, ideia que, aparentemente, foi deixada de lado a favor de uma arquitetura mais simples.

Este Bean funciona em conjunto com este:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Que, por sua vez, usa este:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.codehaus.xfire.spring.remoting.Jsr181HandlerMapping">
    <property name="typeMappingRegistry" ref="xfire.typeMappingRegistry" />
    <property name="xfire" ref="xfire" />
    <property name="webAnnotations" ref="webAnnotations" />
</bean>
```

E é aqui que ocorre a chamada ao XFire.

Para resolver, fiz o seguinte, [baseado nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31903094/1314276):

```
<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" /> -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" />

<!--    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" /> -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter" />
```

E:

```
<!--    <bean id="webAnnotations" class="org.codehaus.xfire.annotations.jsr181.Jsr181WebAnnotations" /> -->

<!--    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.codehaus.xfire.spring.remoting.Jsr181HandlerMapping"> -->
<!--        <property name="typeMappingRegistry" ref="xfire.typeMappingRegistry" /> -->
<!--        <property name="xfire" ref="xfire" /> -->
<!--        <property name="webAnnotations" ref="webAnnotations" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
```

Com isso, posso remover o XFire do Maven.